# What is idiomatic Clojure for this simple logic?

Tags: clojure, idioms

I have written a simple contrived auth function in Clojure and it doesn't feel very idiomatic to me at all.  Is there a better way of writing this:

```
(defn auth [username password] 
  (let [user-record (credential-fn username)]
    (if (and user-record (verify-pw password))
      (let [user-record (dissoc user-record :password)]
        {:status 200 :body user-record})
      {:status 401})))
```

I thought it might be possible to get rid of the `if` by using `if-let`, but the `if` is doing a boolean check and I need to bind the `user-record`? Stuck!

NOTE: the `dissoc` is removing the password from `user-record` so it's not returned in the body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the biggest problem with your function is that it tries to handle three things at once:

1. Checking if username and password are valid for a user (`credential-fn` and `verify-pw`)
2. Cleaning up the record data `(dissoc user-record password)`
3. Building a Ring response map (`{:status 401}` vs. `{:status 200 :body user-record}`)

I would consider splitting your code into two separate functions:

```
(defn authenticate
  [username password]
  (and (verify-pw password) 
       (dissoc (credential-fn username) :password)))

(defn login
  [username password]
  (if-let [user-record (authenticate username password)]
    {:status 200 :body user-record}
    {:status 401}))
```

Comment: I like this version much better as it's separating things into separate functions which is what I was looking for.  The only problem here is that the `verify-pw` is being done before reading the user record via `credential-fn` which is fine for this contrived example but I think in the real scenario I need to read the user-record first then verify the password but that would make authenticate return a boolean would it not?

Comment: Also, when reading `login` it's not obvious that `authenticate` will remove the password from the map.  For me, that would be the responsibility of the `login` because it is dealing with the response map.

Comment: @PaulDrummond, I mostly just took your code and reordered it (so the order might be incorrect). It seems weird though that the neither `verify-pw` or `credential-fn` need both the username and password to check the user is valid.

In my example I tried to portray that authenticating a user is lower-level logic (service-logic?) and cleaning up the data of sensitive data such as passwords should be done there.

Comment: I would consider something like (and (user-exists? username) (verify-pad username password) (credential-fn username)) and define credential-fn not to return potentially 'risky' data like password or password hash. This would reduce the likelihood of someone making a simple mistake. In reality, you will probably need something a little more complex as the current example does not feed back any information on why authentication failed i.e. bad username or bad password etc.